# is there performance difference between binary and text mode while writing to a file in c?

Tags: c, file, binary

I am trying to write a large sum of data to a file. Some suggested i should use binary mode but i already have done it in text mode. Is there a big difference in using the binary in terms of speed? What is the advantage or disadvantage in using the binary mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the binary mode the data gets written unchanged. In the text mode, there can be some additional code to handle `'\n'` and `'\r'` (in DOS/Windows `'\n'` expands into `'\r\n'`). At any rate, disk speeds are orders of magnitude lower than the RAM speed and I wouldn't be too much concerned about the mode here, unless, of course, it turns out that caching is different in the two modes.

Answer (score 3):

Text mode does newline translation, so that

```
fprintf(myfile, "\n");
```

can generate one byte (0x0a, line feed) on Unix-like systems, and two (0x0d,0x0a, carriage return followed by line feed) on Windows. This takes time, since it means each byte has to be inspected. If that really matters when compared to the speed of the I/O system is of course  highly variable.